# undefined reference to `GetPerformanceInfo@8'

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I get the above titled error when compiling this program.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <psapi.h>

#define DIV 1048576
#define WIDTH 7


int main(){

     MEMORYSTATUSEX statex;
     statex.dwLength = sizeof (statex);
     GlobalMemoryStatusEx (&statex);

     PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION statex2;
     statex2.cb=sizeof(statex2);
     GetPerformanceInfo(&statex2,statex2.cb);


     FILE *f=fopen("file.txt","w");
     if(f==NULL){
        printf("error opening the file");
        exit(1);
     }
     fprintf(f,"There is  %*ld percent of memory in use.\n",WIDTH, statex.dwMemoryLoad);
     fprintf(f,"There are %*I64d total MB of physical memory.\n",WIDTH, statex.ullTotalPhys/DIV);
     fprintf(f,"There are %*I64d free  MB of physical memory.\n",WIDTH, statex.ullAvailPhys/DIV);

     fprintf(f,"There is %d processes currently in the system",statex2.ProcessCount);

     return 0;


}
```

what is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683210%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> To ensure correct resolution of symbols, add Psapi.lib to the
>   TARGETLIBS macro and compile the program with –DPSAPI_VERSION=1. To
>   use run-time dynamic linking, load Psapi.dll.

Comment: when i compile the program with -l psapi.dll, it says cannot find -lpsapi.dll

Answer (score 0):

MSDN for [`GetPerformanceInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683210%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) provides you linking instructions on the bottom of the page.

You have a linkerg error, which means you don't link to the library that resolves reference to `GetPerformanceInfo` function, which is `psapi.lib` (or `kernel32.lib` - refer to MSDN for details). You need to add this `.LIB` (not the `.DLL`!) to the linker inputs.

With MS compiler you typically simply add to source code:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "psapi.lib")
```

Comment: how do i do that with MinGW compiler

Comment: It's `-l` on command line: [How do I specify the libraries to be searched by the linker?](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Specify_the_libraries_for_the_linker_to_use)